# Sequelize makes wrong query when I make the fieldName to be changed and include it

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

One of my Sequelize model looks like this,

```js
Sequelize.define('unit', {
  ...
  complex_id: { // 'complex_id' is a key to use in my script
    field: 'building_id', // There's a field named 'building_id' in my 'complex' table
    reference: {
      model: 'complex',
      key: 'id'
    },
  },
  building_id: { // 'building_id' is a key to use in my script
    field: 'immeuble_id', // There's a field named 'immeuble_id' in my 'immeuble' table
    reference: {
      model: 'building',
      key: 'id',
    },
  },
})
```

It would be confusing because of the building_id, but there's a long story behind it.

I was trying to find units where field 'complex_id' has specific value, which means the field named 'building_id' in unit table.

It seems fine when I'm directly selecting unit

```js
unit.findAndCount({
  where: { complex_id: 123 }
})
// => SELECT * FROM unit WHERE building_id = 123
```

However, when I try to select the another entity and include the unit, it works in strange way

```js
another_entity.findAndCount({
  where: {  },
  include: [{
    model:unit,
    where: { complex_id: 123 },
  }],
})
// => SELECT * FROM onother_entity INNER JOIN unit ON .... AND immeble_id = 123
```

Sequelize converts 'complex_id' to 'building_id'.

***However it doesn't stop converting until it changes 'complex_id' to 'immeuble_id'***

I have no idea why Sequelize acts like this. What should I do to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
another_entity.findAndCount({
  where: {"$unit.complex_id$": 123},
  include: [unit]
})
```